# How to convert .dll.refresh to a project reference when converting an ASP.NET website to a Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I have a slew of ASP.NET websites that need to be converted to Web Applications.  These sites all reference the same massive set of *.dll.refresh files to get assemblies from a shared lib folder that has a deep directory structure (we're using source control with the .dll.refresh files).  Manually referencing these 120+ assemblies in the new web application projects is very cumbersome (having to include them one-at-a-time since you can't just recursively grab them through a folder structure), and the process will need to be repeated several times for each conversion.  Is there a way to easily convert these .dll.refresh files into assembly references, or perhaps, is there a better way of getting the assemblies referenced?